# Node js and mongo , pre, post hook middleware are not executed on findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, keystonejs

I have a schema named vehicle where I can add data from the admin and also I can add data importing a csv file. I am using keystone js by the way.

Now when i add data from the admin the hook is triggered and hit but when I add data from my import csv file code the hook is not hit and triggered although the data is added to the database

can we trigger the pre save hook using Vehicle.model.findOneAndUpdat ?

## my importing csv code snippet

```
exports.import = function (req, res) {

    let file = fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.path)


    Papa.parse(file, {
        header: true,
        worker: true,
        preview: prev_val,

        complete: function (results) {

            let vehicles = _.each(results.data, function (value, key) {


                let condition = { VIN: value.VIN }

                Vehicle.model.findOneAndUpdate(condition, value, { upsert: true, new: true }, function (err, doc) {



                    }
```

## Admin UI

When i add data from here the hook is hit anf triggered
[image: my admin -]

## Hook

```
  schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    console.log("HIT" , hit)
    if (this.isNew) {
      next()
    } else {
      console.log("this._original" , this._original)
      console.log("this._original1" , this)
      this._diff = getDiff(this, this._original)
      next()
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From official [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate):

> This function triggers the following middleware. `findOneAndUpdate()`

So, it won't trigger `pre('save')` middleware. Instead you should use `pre('findOneAndUpdate')` middleware. Related official doc [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre).